# How to dynamically size collectionview cell height with fixed width using autolayout?

Tags: ios, dynamic, autolayout, uicollectionviewcell

I've read through all the stack overflow posts describing how to dynamically calculate the height of UITableView cells setup with autolayout and I'm able to successfully implement that.

My question is with doing the same thing for collection view cells. The problem is in `collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:` when I call `[collectionViewCell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize]`, it returns a size that is compressed for both the height AND width.

Is there any way to get back the compressed size with the width being fixed at the contentView's original value? So, essentially getting the compressed height for a fixed width?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     return CGSizeMake(STATIC_WIDTH, [collectionViewCell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height);
}
```

Hope this works out. Let me know :)

Comment: This works usually, but it will not work if the height of the cell is dependent on the width (with aspect ratios for instance).